# How do I add uiimage left of uilabel in stackview?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I'd like to accomplish the following result:
[image]

When I add the uilabel and uiimage to a stackview, no matter what I do the size of the image increases to original so it looks like:

[BIG IMAGE] small text

How do I fix this?

Comment: did you set imageview's contentMode to .scaleAspectFit??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To the image view, add a constraint to set its height to be equal to the Label.
2. Set the image view to have an aspect ratio of 1 : 1.
3. Make sure the stack view itself has constraints to determine its height and width.

Your result will look like this.[image]